# Rename multiple files

Tags: scripting, rename

*Preface: I am an absolute novice with Linux, please don't judge strictly.*

I have a directory containing several images (over 100) of a .pnm extension. I wish to rename them in such a sense, that their names should be "img1.pnm", "img2.pnm", "img3.pnm", etc. So they should have a common part in their names––"img" and different indicies running from "1".

How can I do this?

Comment: How are they named now?

Comment: @UVV img1.pnm, img2.pnm, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following...

```
unset i; for f in *.pnm; do mv "$f" "img$((++i)).pnm";done
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 ls *.pnm | awk -F. '{printf "mv %s img%d.pnm\n",$0,NR;}' | bash
```

where

- `ls *.pnm |` make a list of pnm's file
- `awk -F. '{printf "mv %s img%d.pnm\n",$0,NR;}'` launch awk

  - -F. use . as separator
  - `'{printf "mv %s img%d.pnm\n",$0,NR;}'` print instruction to move and number file.
- `| bash` instruction are give to bash.

you can even preview with

```
ls *.pnm | awk -F. '{printf "mv %s img%d.pnm\n",$0,NR;}'
```

Comment: I've tried this way and the names were successfully changed, however I cannot open a single file after it. Something happened to the files themselves